# Taxonomy List with Node Count, exclude those with 0

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I have a view that is used to display blog categories on a blog with the corresponding count of blog posts in that category. In cases where there are 0 blog posts, I want to exclude that item from the list. Here is my view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'blog_categories';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Blog Categories';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Blog Categories';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Header: Global: Unfiltered text */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['id'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['field'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['content'] = 'Categories:';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content with term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Field: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['prefix'] = '(';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['suffix'] = ')';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'blog_categories' => 'blog_categories',
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Blog Categories Menu Block';
$translatables['blog_categories'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Blog Categories'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Categories:'),
  t('node'),
  t('Block'),
  t('Blog Categories Menu Block'),
);
```

Here is a screenshot of the view config page and one of the output:

[image]

How do I configure the view to exclude terms with a 0 count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the count NID field as a filter:

1. Add new filter
2. Select Content: Nid
3. Set Aggregation type to Count DISTINCT
4. Set Relationship to node (should be default)
5. Set Operator to Is greater than
6. Set Value to 0

Here is the new view:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'blog_categories';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Blog Categories';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Blog Categories';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Header: Global: Unfiltered text */
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['id'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['field'] = 'area_text_custom';
$handler->display->display_options['header']['area_text_custom']['content'] = 'Categories:';
/* Relationship: Taxonomy term: Content with term */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'taxonomy_index';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Field: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['prefix'] = '(';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nid']['suffix'] = ')';
/* Filter criterion: Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'blog_categories' => 'blog_categories',
);
/* Filter criterion: COUNT(DISTINCT Content: Nid) */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['operator'] = '>';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['nid']['value']['value'] = '0';

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block');
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Blog Categories Menu Block';
$translatables['blog_categories'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Blog Categories'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Categories:'),
  t('node'),
  t('Block'),
  t('Blog Categories Menu Block'),
);
```